# QR code detection issue from photo using openCV

Tags: android, opencv, qr-code

I am currently working on an android application, that should be able to detect a QR code from a picture taken. It is not necessary to decode the QR code because it's only needed to calibrate the camera. 
I am using openCV and when I tried to detect the QR code from the original downloaded picture of the QR code it works fine. That's the code I used:

```
bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.qrcodemitzeugs);
Mat img =new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,img)
Mat points= new Mat();
QRCodeDetector detector=new QRCodeDetector();
boolean data = detector.detect(img, points);
```

But when I try the same Code on a photo taken with my smartphone's camera, the QR code doesn't get detected. I searched for a solution and found that maybe the contrast wasn't high enough so converted the picture into binary using following code:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(img,img2,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(img2,img2,100,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

It returned the whole image in black and white but still the QR code wasn't detected.
Did I do something wrong or is there a solution for this problem?

[One of the images i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrvsA.jpg)
I had to resize the picture before uploading it

Comment: Could you add images you were using and the images that were returned so that it is easier for us to understand and help you.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem, by resizing the Mat to a max of 1200x1200. Apparently the OpenCV QRCodeDetector can only handle Mats between ca. 85x85 and ca. 1200x1200, in which the QR Code itself has to have  at least a size of ca. 80x80. I tested this with the image of the original QR Code, which had a size of 600x600. I resized it until the QR Code wasn't detected anymore.